# Orthonormal basis for Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Usually, an orthonormal basis for Hilbert space means an orthonormal subset which unconditionally spans the whole space.

However, I'm curious whether there exists an orthonormal basis for every Hilbert space in algebraic sence. That is, if $H$ is a Hilbert space, does there exist a maximal linearly independent subset $\beta$ which is orthonormal? This would be false, but I cannot find a counterexample. What would it be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: in a separable Hilbert space ?

Comment: Is it true for separable Hilbert spaces?

Comment: in a separable Hilbert space, you know that if $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis, then for any $x \in H$ : $\|x - \sum_{n \le N} \langle e_n,x \rangle e_n \| \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$   (and this why we are allowed to write $x = \sum_n \langle e_n,x\rangle e_n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, an orthonormal basis is not a basis in the algebraic sense. Suppose not: let $B$ be such an orthonormal basis.  Let $b_1, b_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of distinct members of $B$ and $x = \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j/j$.  If $x = \sum_{b \in B} c_b b$ (where only finitely many $c_b \ne 0$), then $c_b = \langle b, x \rangle$.
But $c_{b_j} = 1/j \ne 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! I get what exactly you mean. However, it's off the topic but there is a point I don't get. Why does $\sum b_j/j$ converge? I see $\sum b_j/j^2$ converges by comparison test but not sure why $\sum b_j/j$ converges.

Comment: Hint: $$\left\|\sum_{j=n+1}^m b_j/j\right\|^2 = \sum_{j=n+1}^m 1/j^2 < 1/n$$